# Decryption using private key issue in Android

Tags: android, encryption, rsa, private-key

I am getting an encrypted string from the backend server, which I need to decrypt using private key in Android.The decryption works, but it appends a special character at the end of the decrypted string.
Here is the code I am using:

```
public static String decryptString(String value, Context context){

    value = "Ss7LVqgWeamgPGkt62qSNydTJnwiUet8UemYWR0jzCLOvtW+RazpJmGG657/nWhu5UQGXzEMwIK1jcBXIXkw3EAX6WdocYBKpVJPWpmlEbf4IzPcev67wgx4vd3ylK8KrpPDj92EKE6ElDi/U91e+VS3bhURHye0w9ncaITTm+szGFiDL/fcy+0hnrYJdA3IrElZntYk14SCccb2M0LJ+nTFdfzEgsUH8vW5ei986d4HTKUqBvkoU+JAtHXTYq1sKNSd4L3Xm5fZ0OPpdIKEWqHDntjsMRsX62eTON+iC1OVsKK2vRqvSbVLvE45ww3N6iZNBG1gewcC8v5wJwonmA==";
    byte[] decodedBytes = null;
    try {
        //Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding", "AndroidOpenSSL");
        //Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding", "AndroidOpenSSL");
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "AndroidOpenSSL");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,  getPrivateKey(context) );

        decodedBytes = c.doFinal(Base64.decode(value, Base64.DEFAULT));


        //decodedBytes = c.doFinal(value.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new String(decodedBytes);
}  

public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(Context context){

    // reads the key_public key stored in a file
    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.key_private);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;

    try {


        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            lines.add(line);


        // removes the first and last lines of the file (comments)
        if (lines.size() > 1 && lines.get(0).startsWith("-----") && lines.get(lines.size()-1).startsWith("-----")) {
           lines.remove(0);
         lines.remove(lines.size()-1);
        }

        // concats the remaining lines to a single String
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String aLine: lines)
            sb.append(aLine);
        String keyString = sb.toString();
        byte [] encoded = Base64.decode(keyString, Base64.DEFAULT);



    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        PrivateKey myPrivKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

        return myPrivKey;

    }catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

Finally, I call the first function from the main activity:

```
String decryptedString =  AppUtils.decryptString(encryptedString, MainActivity.this);
```

I am attaching my private key for reference:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Here is the output:

```
NDcxMDQ3MjguMTQ2ODg3NTI4MTr4iAAldbBVX2RD3cNw/rlKpmOp1p8YXIYqUVlvX7rmgg==��
```

The decrypted string should end with "==".Can someone kindly help me to figure out, how to remove the special characters at the end of the decrypted string.

Thanks

Comment: Which characters are the special characters?

Comment: The last 2 question marks at the end of the decrypted string

Comment: I know that, but what *are* the special characters? Do they have an ASCII value?

Comment: More to the point what are thee values of the last two characters in hex as it seems they are not ASCII printable characters.?

Comment: This is the bytecode array as Hexadecimal string:
4E4463784D4451334D6A67754D5451324F4467334E5449344D5472346941416C646242565832524433634E772F726C4B706D4F70317038595849597155566C765837726D67673D3D00

where the last 2 characters is 00

Answer (score 0):

These values at the end must have been added during encryption. They are probably `00` valued bytes that were added by a language with null terminated strings or similar. The point is that PKCS#1 unpadding will fail if the ciphertext itself is altered, so the only reasonable explanation is that the values have been included in the plaintext.

Print out the `decodedBytes` in hexadecimals to find out the values. You can likely get rid of them by using the `String#trim()` method.

Comment: And note that the fact that base 64 is encrypted instead of the byte array that is represented should already show you that the person that has created the encryption method doesn't have a clue...